# fastboot devices returns nothing while adb devices does

Tags: rooting

Device is OnePlus 3. I'm unsure of why this is happening - I have made sure to install the fastboot and adb drivers correctly, however fastboot devices does nothing when I put it into cmd even though the adb devices returns my phone normally.

Comment: Do you connect the phone in Fastboot mode? If so, does it appear in Device manager?

Comment: Booted phone in fastboot mode and it shows up in Windows 10 device manager after I enable "USB connected to switch files" instead of just charging from swipe down menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution - I needed to enable the installation of unsigned drivers on my system (Windows 10) and manually install the OnePlus bootloader driver while the phone was plugged in and in fastboot mode.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use fastboot you need to boot to fastboot. If adb does list your device you can use `adb reboot-bootloader` to reboot to the bootloader (fastboot). Now you can see your device with `fastboot devices`

Comment: I boot my phone in fastboot mode and it doesn't show up!

Comment: And adb shows your device if you are in fastboot?

Comment: Yes it does, one thing - when I boot in fastboot mode, once I reach the BIOS-esque screen saying I'm in fastboot mode should I stay there, or navigate to and press start using the power button to complete the fastboot mode boot?

Comment: As long as adb shows your device, you are not in fastboot... or you don't have the drivers needed. My HTC doesn't need any drives but according to http://www.technobuzz.net/download-oneplus-3-usb-drivers/ you need usb and fastboot drivers for your oneplus 3.